# Mac keyboard shortcuts not working on iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, keyboard, ios-simulator, macos-high-sierra

All the mac keyboard short cuts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (Quit Simulator app), <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (Toggle keyboard hide/show in Simulator) etc has stopped workings for iOS Simulator app since this morning suddenly.

All other apps, including Xcode, shows the shortcut in menus and they are working fine.

I noticed, the shortcut keys shows up against menu items momentarily on launch of simulator but then disappears completely (see attached)...

[image]

I tried following but no success...

- Launch simulator (Open Xcode project and then menu Product > Run. And, directly through menu Xcode > Open Developer Tools).
- Erase All Content and Settings in Simulator...
- Restart Mac

**Xcode 9.0.1 (9A1004) | Mac 10.13 (17A405)**

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You might have enabled (checked) the "Send all keyboard shortcuts to device" mode. It's in the Hardware > Keyboard submenu.

Pressing both Left and Right <kbd>Cmd</kbd> keys at the same time will exit keyboard capturing mode and re-enable menu shortcuts.

Comment: i.e. you need to DISABLE the "Send All Keyboard Shortcuts To Device" in order to make your keyboard shortcuts work again as the OP expect.

Comment: My good luck i read this second answer. I believe we all prefer not manually deleting internal files unless there is no way around :)

Comment: This really helped. Thank you so much. I thought I was going crazy or that I screwed up my repo.

Comment: Thanks that real help.

Answer (score 8):

You might have disabled(unchecked) "Connect hardware keyboard" option which is in the hardware/keyboard menu. Make sure its checked.

Comment: In my case `Connect hardware keyboard` was enabled, disabling it worked, thanks anyways for pointing to this +1

Answer (score 2):

[image: Set which key stops capture shortcut]

You may need to press the `esc` key on newer versions of the simulator.
You can also choose which key stops shortcut capture.