# React-native, iOS simulator stops responding to CMD + D

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator

since a couple of months I'm facing a very strange situation, when developing on the latest versions of react native (0.50+ to 0.60+) the iOS simulator stops responding to keyboard commands, that is:

- Simulator starts, I can hit Cmd+R or Cmd+D just fine for a few cycles
- After some hot reload cycles, the commands completely stop working
- If go to `Hardware->Keyboard->Send Keyboard Shortcuts` and enabled it, the commands start working again
- However then the `Cmd+Shift+H` doesn't work anymore so I cannot easily close the app if I have to

This is really driving me crazy, has anybody faced the same situation or knows any workaround? Many thanks!

P.S. I already tried a few months ago to reset everything (including simulator settings and xcode installation)

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044924/mac-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-on-ios-simulator . Let me know if it helped you or not, otherwise I can look into it some more.

Comment: Well, that answer is saying the same thing that I did, which is enabling sending the shortcuts to device, but then the home shortcut does not work anymore, it is not a solution

Comment: Do you have `Connect hardware keyboard` enabled, if so, uncheck it. And are you sure you didn't press Left + Right command keys at the same time? This will exit keyboard capturing mode and re-enable menu shortcuts.

Comment: yes, I'm sure, like I said, everything is working and then after some hot-reload cycles it completely stops listening to keyboard commands

Comment: The same happens to me since some months ago. I've checked and it's not the "Connect Hardware Keyboard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that pressing `R` `R` reloads the app on the latest react-native versions, same as on the android emulator, so maybe this is an intentional change.

**For those coming in nowadays**
In any case, so far the workarounds seem to be:

- `cmd` + `shift` + `z` to trigger the dev menu and then click on reload
- `r` `r` sometimes also does the trick
- `d` if the simulator is focused

Comment: Neither of these work for me. XCode 12.5, react-native "0.63.4"

Comment: if cmd + shift + z is not working for you, then you have probably disabled keyboard events on the simulator itself

Answer (score 27):

I'm having the same issue. Seems to be an iOS 13.3+ simulator issue as you can see in this thread:

[iOS Simulator CMD+R CMD+D Shake doesn't work at all after some time](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27384)

As an alternative, `command + ctrl + z` still works to access the development menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been seeing this issue before 13.3 was released... over a year I think, but command + ctrl + z works

Comment: For me cmd + ctrl + z opens up the menu twice

Comment: When i hit crazily AND alternatively command + i or d or r, it sometimes works. Maybe a "shortcut listener" in ios simulator or in reactNative is not enough fast.

Answer (score 6):

For me pressing "D" then "⌘+D" solves the issue.

The same goes for "R" then "⌘+R".

Not sure if you could actually just press any single key before pressing your desired shortcut.

[Kudos to this GitHub answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27384#issuecomment-636703810) for helping me out as this was an extremely frustrating issue.

UPDATE:
Since Xcode 12.5 the shortcut for recording the simulator screen is now also CMD+R. This swallows the first CMD+R because instead it starts recording the simulator screen. The next CMD+R will reload the screen. Fortunately, this can be [fixed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31467#issuecomment-835352650).

Comment: Kudos man, this was really frustrating issue.

Comment: Cheers mate, saving me minutes over the course of a day!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you are in Debug Mode and not in Release?

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... >

Build Configuration: Debug + check the box Debug executable.

After changing Scheme, better to deinstall your app.

Also I noticed the Cmd D doesn't work during Splashscreen.

[image: Xcode Product Scheme]

[image: Scheme configuration: Debug and check Debug executable]